# Kibana / Elastic - Group values from "available fields"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, askql

I would like to merge certain values.

---

**Example**:

Kibana currently gives me for "car_model" as a "available field" e.g. C200, C180,, A4, A6, C220, Golf 6, Golf 7. I now want to put all C-models into one group, so that the C-class contains: C200 & C180 & C220. You can see in the picture what I mean ['1'].
[image]
**Then I can compare them all**:
C-Class: 100.000
A6: 90.000
Golf 6: 50.000
Golf 7: 80.000

---

Currently there is no other way to import the data into Kibana, so I would like to solve it this way. Does anyone have an idea how I can merge these values into a group and compare all grouped values in a dashboard? Maybe via SQL or KQL?. Thank you in advance.

---